# AS3/Flash: Is it possible to sort a datagrid based on a hidden column?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sorting, datagrid

Flash CS5 / AS3

I have a four columns Datagrid. The last columne must be hidden:

```
Name | Surname | City | Hidden //<---date-stamp
```

I would like to sort it dynamically based on the hidden column values (are numeric and unique)

Comment: It should work. Did you try it before asking?

Comment: Yes, I did try yesterday without luck. Anyway, I was exhausted. I'll do a new research. Cheers.

Comment: No luck. Getting the same material. No one explains how to force the sort to a especific column.

Comment: Not putting this as answer as I don't have CS5. In Flash Builder (Flex) though, you can use something like http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/collections/Sort.html#includeExamplesSummary and change <s:GridColumn dataField="first"/> to <s:GridColumn dataField="first" visible="false"/>. I hope CS5 components have similar API.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
datagrid.sortItemsOn("hiden", Array. NUMERIC);
```